# Python3.4.3 Nmap : Host discovery with Operating System detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, scanning, nmap

Trying to run this Host Discovery with python-nmap module:
(I do not know how to print out the hosts name because there is almost none documentation on how to use it).
I wish to be able to see each the OS of each device on my network.

```
import nmap
nm = nmap.PortScanner()

nm.scan(hosts='192.168.2.1/24', arguments='-sS -O')
for host in nm.all_hosts():
    #print the host and the Operating system
```

If you know a good tutorial on how to use python-nmap, please tell me!
I am running on a mac 10.10.5 and I know how to use nmap.
If you know how to print the host discovery and maybe other useful tags, please help me here =)
Running on python 3.4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nmap.PortScanner.all_hosts` returns a list of strings (ip addresses).

Simply printing `host` will give you host addresses.

To get OS information use `nm[host]['osclass']`:

```
for host in nm.all_hosts():
    print(host)
    print(nm[host].get('osclass', 'unknown'))
    # {'vendor': 'Linux', 'accuracy': '100', 'type': 'general purpose',
    #  'osfamily': 'Linux', 'osgen': '3.X'}
```

Comment: I'm trying it at the moment, can you tell me how you found that information? I tried to find some documentation but the xael.org didn't really provide good information...

Comment: @bob, I read the [Usage](http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/#usage). In the usage example, you can see that `nm.all_hosts()` returns a list of `str`: `['127.0.0.1']`

Comment: I'm sorry but my problem is to get the OS (operating system) of each device (in nmap it is -O)

Comment: Worked for 192.168.2.1 but when it came to the next one(192.168.2.108) it crashed with this error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "okok.py", line 7, in <module>
    print (nm[host]['osclass'])
KeyError: 'osclass'

Comment: @bob, Catch the `KeyError` exception or use `dict.get`: `print(nm[host].get('osclass', 'Unknown'))` . I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Brilliant! It works perfectly, one last thing. I wish to understand, how or where did you find how to print the OS?

Comment: @bob, I just printed `nm[host]`, then it was a dictionary. I looked for `os*`, and there was `osclass`. That's it. I planned to see the source code if I couldn't find `os*`.

Comment: we can also use `–script=smb-os-discovery`